# How to ignore offset in Jekyll when previous post is skipped

Tags: jekyll, liquid, offset, posts

I'm trying to create my first blog on Jekyll. I'm stuck on one thing: I have a section for one of my categories, let's say "news":

```
<section class="news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        
{% for post in site.categories.news limit: 2 offset: 0 %} 
{% include news-item-col-6.html %}
{% endfor %}

{% for post in site.categories.news limit: 3 **offset: 2** %}
{% include news-item-col-4.html %}
{% endfor %}
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

***news-item-col-6:***

```
{% if post.thumb != 0 %}
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="pattern">
            <div class="overlay item-title" style="background-image: url({{ post.thumb }});">               
                <div class="item-title-content">
                    <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.header }}</a></h3>                     
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

***news-item-col-4:***

```
{% if post.thumb != 0 %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pattern">           
        <div class="overlay item-title" style="background-image: url({{ post.thumb }});">
            <div class="item-title-content">
                <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.header }}</a></h3>                 
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

***my posts tp***

```
---
layout: post
title: title | site.com
header: title
description: description
categories: categories url
catname: News
image: "images/URL /to image/1.jpg"
thumb: "images/URL /to thumb/1t.jpg"
permalink: "blog/:categories/:year-:month-:day-:slug.html"
---
```

The problem is that not all of my posts will have background thumb, and all I want to do is to ignore the posts which has no `post.thumb`. and the code is works, but unfortunately `col-md-4` block's offset is not ignoring post's order with no `post.thumb`.

The pictures below shows what I want:

- [This is how should be, if all my posts have post.thumb(bg_image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkJ3c.jpg)
- [This is how should be, if my post Item2 has no post.thumb(bg_image), it just not showing up in section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xly7Q.jpg)
- [And this is how my code works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOAjT.jpg)

So what should I do to make it work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a custom counter, like this:

```html
{% assign counter = 0 %} <!-- create a custom counter and set it to zero -->
{% for post in site.categories.news %} <!-- loop through the posts in news -->
  {% if post.thumb %} <!-- check if the post has a thumbnail -->
    {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %} <!-- increment the counter if it does -->
    {% if counter < 3 %} <!-- if this is the first or second counted post -->
      {% include news-item-col-6.html %} <!-- include the col-6 element -->
    {% elsif counter < 6 %} <!-- else -->
      {% include news-item-col-4.html %} <!-- include the col-4 element -->
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry for annoying, can u explain each your step, if u don’t mind, I’m really in beginning in web dev. So I’m trying to understand all code I wright than just copy/past, you know..

Comment: No problem. I have added comments (in HTML format).

Comment: i found another bug, as my section has to has limited list of posts(5), i added limit for 5 posts in string {% for post in site.categories.news limit:5 %}, then i created 6 posts, but from last post(newest) i deleted thumb to cheak how it will work, and counter did his job, but limit were still counting first post as it appeared and jekyll genereted last first 4 posts (+ 1st post wich was hided)  and 6th one he didnt showed on 5th place.

Comment: You did not find a bug, but you have added feature request. I have added your feature (limit to 5).

Comment: Sorry, didn’t understand, what do u mean u have added feature (limit to 5), where?

Comment: {% elsif counter < 6 %}

Comment: Hi, would u mind to cheak this question  for me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048638/how-in-jekyll-for-categories-html-write-a-logic-for-posts-in-specific-category